# Can't make CefSharp load synchronous

Tags: c#, async-await, chromium-embedded, cefsharp

I have an off screen `ChromiumWebBrowser` that I use to run some JS on a page and get back the results.

The Load method is synchronous, but I can't run JS code until the FrameLoadEnd event is raised, which means that or my purposes Load is an asynchronous method that ends in the FrameLoadEnd event.

To make my code clearer, I tried to create an extension method that will allow me to wait for the page to load using `await` instead of registering to the event. But when I use this method with TaskCompletionSource the javascript that is supposed to run after the page loads isn't loaded, but when using an `AutoResetEvent` and waiting on it the code does work.

This code doesn't work:

```
public static Task LoadPageAsync(this IWebBrowser browser, string address)
{
    TaskCompletionSource<bool> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
    browser.FrameLoadEnd += (sender, args) =>
    {
        if (args.IsMainFrame)
        {
            tcs.TrySetResult(true);
        }
    };
    browser.Load(address);
    return tcs.Task;
}
```

And this does:

```
public static AutoResetEvent LoadPageAsync(this IWebBrowser browser, string address)
{
    AutoResetEvent are = new AutoResetEvent(false);
    browser.FrameLoadEnd += (sender, args) =>
    {
        if (args.IsMainFrame)
        {
            are.Set();
        }
    };
    browser.Load(address);
    return are;
}
```

This is the calling code:

```
await _browser.LoadPageAsync("Some web address");
LoadScripts();

DoJsThing();
GetJsData();
```

They do the same thing but I feel that the intent of the function is much clearer when returning a task than when returning an AutoResetEvent.

Why can't I use TaskCompletionSource to indicate I finished? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You `await` on the page load, not on the javascript load which comes later in `LoadScripts()`, right?

Comment: Wait, is `Load` a synchronous method?

Comment: Load is synchronous, but doesn't do anything meaningful (or at least anything that I care for) until the main frame is loaded. Which means that in regular code, I'd call the Load and then the rest of my program will continue in the event code for FrameLoadEnd, which causes odd jumps through the code.

Comment: And the event should occur right after the page is loaded?

Comment: The event is raised by the library after the page is loaded, yes.

Comment: Does the `await` just block and never return?

Comment: No, because Load starts an asynchronous operation of loading the webpage on a separate process and the event is raised at some point after the task is awaited.

Comment: Can you fork the `MinimalExample` to demo your exact problem?

https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.MinimalExample

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
public static Task LoadPageAsync(IWebBrowser browser, string address = null)
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>(TaskCreationOptions.RunContinuationsAsynchronously);

    EventHandler<LoadingStateChangedEventArgs> handler = null;
    handler = (sender, args) =>
    {
        //Wait for while page to finish loading not just the first frame
        if (!args.IsLoading)
        {
            browser.LoadingStateChanged -= handler;
            //Important that the continuation runs async using TaskCreationOptions.RunContinuationsAsynchronously
            tcs.TrySetResult(true);
        }
    };

    browser.LoadingStateChanged += handler;

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(address))
    {
        browser.Load(address);
    }
    return tcs.Task;
}
```

Note I used `LoadingStateChanged` as it's a better indicator of when the whole page has finished loading.

Comment: Thank you, this works. I tried forking the minimal example but couldn't get the problem to reproduce.

Comment: @amaitland I don't see a NavStateChanged event property in [IWebBrowser](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/master/CefSharp/IWebBrowser.cs), where can I find it? Using CefSharp 47.0.2.

Comment: It was renamed to `LoadingStateChanged`, see https://gist.github.com/amaitland/9d8897067bdff5b999a1#file-program-cs-L60 for an example

Comment: This example is good for offscreen solution. Trying to fully load page in WinForms application before showing form itself makes programmer life into nightmare.

Comment: Link has been replaced with code sample which is an extract from a working example found at https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/cefsharp/79/CefSharp.OffScreen.Example/Program.cs#L117